# Apple App store connect error API not working

Tags: python, app-store

I am trying to make an *Apple App Store Connect API* request in Python Jupyter Notebook using the following code and getting the error:

> **error: 401, not authorised, authentication credentials are missing or are invalid.**

```
#make API request
url = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports"

params = {
    'filter[frequency]': 'DAILY',
    'filter[reportType]': 'SALES',
    'filter[reportSubType]': 'SUMMARY',
    'filter[vendorNumber]': 'XXXXXXXX' 
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#apps = response.json()
print(response.text)
```

I created my bearer token following the steps provided by apple Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api, and generating tokens for api requests https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests
I created the following constants and the JWT token using the following code as well as wrote code to see if the token generated was still valid:

```
#Constants
Issuer_ID = "XXXXXXXXx"
Key_ID = "XXXXXXX" 
Secret_key = "/Users/home/Desktop/Apple_API_Key" 
Audience = "appstoreconnect-v1"
token_duration = 1200 #cannot exceed this max amount of else apple will reject request
```

#create the jwt token

```
with open(Secret_key, 'r') as f:
    Secret_key = f.read()

header = {
    'alg':'ES256',
    'kid':Key_ID,
    'typ':'JWT'
}
payload = {
    'iss':Issuer_ID,
    'exp': time.time() + token_duration,
    'aud': Audience
}

token = jwt.encode(payload, Secret_key, algorithm = 'ES256', headers = header)
print(token)

decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
expiration_timestamp = decoded_token['exp']

if time.time() > expiration_timestamp:
    print("The token is expired!")
else:
    print("The token is still valid.")
```

Comment: Does the error really say **authentification**? Also, this isn't really a Python issue - it's a matter of how the API is used

Comment: Yes, this is the full error:
{
 "errors": [{
  "status": "401",
  "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
  "title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",
  "detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"
 }]
}

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. To resolve it, please ensure that you grant **Admin** access during the private key creation process. Additionally, you can try removing `Content-type` from the request header. I read in Apple forum that it helps to some users.

Comment: Hello thanks, the admin owner of my account created the key. I currently have access as a app manager and finance. Do you know if I need admin specifically, as I think that can only be linked to one account. But the administrator of the company did create the key. Will this work ?

Comment: Hey! Just make sure that the admin added those admin privileges when creating the private key. It doesn’t matter if your account is for app manager. The crucial is to make sure that when creating the private key the admin privileges were associated within.